# Automating uploading pdfs to our cloud server

Tags: pdf, script, printing, pdfcreator

I'm trying to simplify the process of getting a document from any Windows program where it was created to our cloud pdf repository, requiring the author to perform as few steps as possible.

Currently the author must generate a PDF file by printing to the pdf driver from the Windows application, name and save this file to a temporary folder on his disk, log into the cloud server, browse for and upload the PDF file to the server, select it and modify its details (i.e. Name, permissions, etc.).

The goal is to provide a seamless print-to-upload single click solution which eliminates as many of these transitional steps as possible.

Does anyone have suggestions for how to do this?  I think the ability to execute a script after generating a pdf would be one way of solving it, but I'm not sure of the best (most seamless) approach.

I found [this](http://www.biopdf.com/guide/run_program_after_pdf_creation.php) pdf writer software, which purports to offer scripting, but have no experience with it.

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: What have you tried so far? We don't really do recommendations here, but we but we help solve problems. What you have asked for is a recommendation. Use the edit button to rephrase and improve your question.

Comment: Edited. Please let me know if this is better. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Set up a samba server, and create a printer out of a shell script.  Said shell script will take PostScript input, run it through `ps2pdf`, outputting the result as a PDF file, naming it the attached user's username with a timestamp on it (ie, `ivan-201901122228.pdf`) and then it will upload to cloud via `sftp`, `scp`, a `curl` command, or whatever else is needed.

Install the printer like any other server-attached network printer, use any color printer driver that is for PostScript (I like the built-in drivers for HP Color LaserJet printers, just pick one that says "PS" next to it!), and simply print to the device.

You can do the same thing and send faxes using `hylafax` as well....

Comment: A samba server never occurred to me. That's a good idea.